# Where to place the sqljdbc.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, tomcat7, classnotfoundexception

I'm developing this Java app, everything works fine in eclipse
but this program will not run with Apache Tomcat 7.0 because it cannot find the sqlserver driver.

This app is suppose to connect to a sqlserver 2005 database, but it will not get past the `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")`, on the server side.

I know it's that line because I found:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

in my log file. I placed the `sqljdbc.jar` in every `catalinaHome/lib`, `catalinaHome/shared/lib`, and `web-inf/lib`.

I also edited the `catalina.properties` so it reads from the `shared/lib` folder.

I'm out of ideas, any help will be awesome!

#### UPDATE #1 - problem solved

I manually included the .class files into the war file and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

CATALINA_HOME/lib should work. Have you restarted Tomcat after that though?

And SQL driver needs some DLLs, [it seems](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2007/06/18/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication.aspx). Do you have them setup correctly? The visible error may still be ClassNotFound because if class fails to initialize statically, it is viewed as class not found at all.

Before deploying the driver to Tomcat, make a small local test - a standalone Java class that loads the driver and tries to connect. May point you to the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The correct place for it is `application/WEB-INF/lib/`. Note the upper-case `WEB-INF`.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on what's loading the library? If the app loads it,this is correct. If Tomcat loads it for you and provides a datasource via JNDI, this won't work.

Comment: @rfeak - yes, but he's not using a datasource as it seems :)

Comment: @rfreak - yea, not using a datasouce

Comment: Understood. I must have missed that in the OP.